# Docker Compose контейнер висит с Exit 143

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Мой сервис запущем в доке-контейнере. При обновлении я выполнил docker-compose stop и docker-compose down, однако контенер не остановился. Команда docker-compose ps показывает

```
myapp-                        /bin/sh -c exec java $JAVA      Exit 143        
test_myapp-1_1_8f0ff5a42794
```

Убрать контейнер из этого списка не получается, запустить сервис повторно тоже невозможно, т.к. зависший контейнер держит порт. Как исправить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Варианты принудительной остановки сервисов

```
docker-compose kill [options] [SERVICE...]
docker-compose rm [options] [SERVICE...]
```

Можно и логи посмотреть, чтобы понять что там случилось

```
docker-compose logs [SERVICE...]
```